# nginx reverse proxy sends all traffic to first defined server

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have multiple servers running on the same host. I am trying to configure nginx to route traffic based on the server_name, but all traffic is sent to the first defined server.

I have two urls:

1. example.domain.net
2. domain.net

which I have configured nginx to proxy with configuration:

```
server {
        listen 3978;
        listen [::]:3978;
        server_name example.domain.net:3978 example.domain.net:3978;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8443;
         }
}
server {
        listen 3978;
        listen [::]:3978;
        server_name domain.net:3978 www.domain.net:3978;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8020;
        }
}
```

But all traffic to both example.domain.net:3978 and domain.net:3978 is being sent to whichever server is defined first in the file (in this case example.domain.net)

I've seen other examples where this worked like [This post](https://serverfault.com/questions/753105/how-to-reverse-proxy-to-different-places-depending-on-subdomain-in-nginx). Is this possible with one having a subdomain and another not?

I am using nginx version 1.18.0 with the default nginx.conf on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: `server_name` should not have port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`server_name` should not have ports. Try removing `:3978` from the server_name.

Because you have the ports, the hostname does not match any of the server_name. So, the entire traffic is sent to the first server which is considered as a default for no matches.